# Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: -1

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am follow the passing value to next page so i can get the data but when i use listview for show the image the app alert
'Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: -1'

where should i fix code?

```
Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                        height: 130.0,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: keepImage.length,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            shrinkWrap: true,

                            // itemCount: 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return InkWell(
                                  child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 8.0,
                                    bottom: 8.0,
                                    left: 8.0,
                                    right: 8.0),
                                child: Container(
                                    height: 140,
                                    width: 140,
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: ClipRRect(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                          child: AspectRatio(
                                            aspectRatio: 1.2,
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: double.infinity,
                                              height: 400,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: FileImage(
                                                          keepImage[index - 1]),
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                    )),
                              ));
                            }),
                      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code  `FileImage(keepImage[index - 1])`. You are subtracting index with 1 which will result in -1. But accepted value in 0 or a value greater than 0. Change it to `FileImage(keepImage[index])`. Then it should work as expected.